# shouldOverrideUrlLoading on custom Cordova CordovaWebViewClient not working anymore

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I had a custom class to override the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading, provided by CordovaWebViewClient.

```
    public class CordovaCustomWebClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

        public CordovaCustomWebClient(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView view) {
            super(cordova, view);
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            EventLogger.logMessage(getClass(), "--------------- shouldOverrideUrlLoading ---------------");
       return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
       }
```

It was working fine until I've upgraded to the latest version of Cordova (3.6.3). Now the function shouldOverrideUrlLoading is no longer being called, but when I debug the code I can see that same function being executed in Cordova library (class CordovaWebViewClient).

Here is what I do to override Cordova's web client:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_application);

        cordovaWebView = (CordovaWebView) this.findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        Config.init(this);

        Application application = null;
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            application = (Application) bundle.get("key_application");
        }

        // Local Url to load application
        String url = "";
        if (application != null) {
            if (HubManagerHelper.getInstance().getApplicationHosted() == null) {
                MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
                app.registerDefaultHubApplication();
            }
            url = String.format(WebServicesClient.URL_WEB_APPLICATION, HubManagerHelper.getInstance()
                    .getApplicationHosted(), application.getPath());
        }

        cordovaWebView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaCustomWebClient(this, cordovaWebView));

        // Listener to Download Web File with Native Component - Download Manager
        cordovaWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
                downloadAndOpenFile(WebApplicationActivity.this, url);
            }
        });

        String ua = cordovaWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
        String appVersion = getAppVersion();
        String newUA = ua.concat(" MyApp." + appVersion);
        cordovaWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            cordovaWebView.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_loading)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hit this exact same problem today after upgrading to 3.6.3. It took looking at the Cordova source code to figure out why this was broken. At some point a new method, `init`, was introduced, which takes a bunch of params read from your config.xml. If that method is not called by your code, then when a url is loaded it will hit the `initIfNecessary` case, which in turn will override any custom clients that were set.

From their code:

```
private void initIfNecessary() {
    if (pluginManager == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "CordovaWebView.init() was not called. This will soon be required.");
        // Before the refactor to a two-phase init, the Context needed to implement CordovaInterface. 
        CordovaInterface cdv = (CordovaInterface)getContext();
        if (!Config.isInitialized()) {
            Config.init(cdv.getActivity());
        }
        init(cdv, makeWebViewClient(cdv), makeWebChromeClient(cdv), Config.getPluginEntries(), Config.getWhitelist(), Config.getExternalWhitelist(), Config.getPreferences());
    }
}
```

You can see that `makeWebViewClient` is called, even though you may have already set your own client.

I solved this with:

```
ConfigXmlParser parser = new ConfigXmlParser();
parser.parse(activity);

CordovaInterface cordova = (CordovaInterface) activity;
init(cordova, new WFWebViewClient(cordova, this), makeWebChromeClient(cordova),
    parser.getPluginEntries(), parser.getInternalWhitelist(), parser.getExternalWhitelist(),
    parser.getPreferences());
```

And removed the deprecated use of `Config.init(activity);`.

Hope this saves you some of the time I've wasted today.

Comment: Thanks Todd! I actually did something different, but the problem was exactly that one. I've created my own custom method makeWebViewClient which checks if there is already one there, and if so it won't replace it. In my scenario that solves it.

@Override
    public CordovaWebViewClient makeWebViewClient(CordovaInterface cordova) {
     if(this.webViewClient == null)
     {
      webViewClient = super.makeWebViewClient(cordova);
     }
     return this.webViewClient;
    }

Comment: I actually like your solution much better and almost refactored mine to override `makeWebViewClient` as well, but the comment in `initIfNecessary` about init being required soon scared me back to just making the unnecessarily complex init call. I'm not sure why we should have to do the config parsing ourselves.

Comment: @ToddT can you please elaborate where you put that code block of yours?